# What is this string array thing please

Tags: arrays, string

Can someone explain this please as I am not familiar with it and it isn't an easy thing to google.

String[] temp;   <--- I know this

String temp[];   <--- What is this?????

Comment: In what programming language you see this code written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are both valid declarations for a string array